# MSSQL query, can't get correct results from Select

Tags: sql-server

Dear smarter people then me,

I'm having an issue with collecting data from a VIEW I have in my SQL database.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT
ref_aanhefinformeel, voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, ref_afdeling,
ref_locatie, ref_plaats1, functie, email, isnull(telefoon, mobiel) as telefoon,
personeelsnr,
CASE
    WHEN geslacht ='1' THEN 'Man'
    ELSE
         CASE WHEN geslacht ='2' THEN 'Vrouw'
         END
    END as Geslacht
FROM VW_telefoonboek where achternaam = 'hovens'
```

It returns the following error:
Invalid column name 'ref_plaats1'. Invalid column name 'ref_locatie'. Invalid column name 'ref_afdeling'. Invalid column name 'ref_aanhefinformeel'.

This is strange because when I Select * from the same VIEW, I do get the data I need from the colomns which data doesnt pop up when I define them.
[image: Labels and Columns on the VIEW]

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post the body of your view

Comment: So when you select * from the View it brings back a column named Plaats and not ref_plaats1 correct?  At least it appears that way from your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say 'Label' do you mean alias?  As in

```
CREATE VIEW VW_telefoonboek AS 
SELECT ref_aanhefinformeel AS Aanhefinformeel,
..etc
FROM UnderlyingTable
```

(Edit after OP added picture of results)
In which case when you select from the view you have to use the alias,i.e.

```
SELECT
Aanheinformeel,
Achternaam,
Voornaam,
Functie,
Afdeling,
Personeelsnr,
Locatie_code,
Mobiel,
Tussenvoegsel,
Vestiging,
Email,
Geslacht,
Telefoon,
Plaats
FROM VW_telefoonboek
```

Comment: I don't know to be honest, can't access the actual database. However if I change it to Naam, it returns the same error telling me Invalid column name 'naam'.

Comment: Where did you get the Label references from then?

Comment: Added a picture with the results of SELECT * FROM [VIEW], I think that might help

Comment: OK So your picture is now showing the aliases assigned, I've amended my answer for one column, please try that.

Comment: That is strange, it seems to be working for 2 of the 4 columns but not for:
Invalid column name 'Plaats1'. Invalid column name 'Locatie'.

Comment: Because they are not aliases, I've edited my answer again with the full list.  Please try that.

Comment: You're welcome - if you do any`where` or `case` statements they need to be based on that list too.

Answer (score 2):

When you run:

```
SELECT * FROM yourview
```

the result is a list of value containted in your columns. From your screenshot you have two columns, the first named **Label** the second named **Kolom**

You try to show, in your `SELECT` columns not existing.

Your query:

```
SELECT
ref_aanhefinformeel, voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, ref_afdeling,
ref_locatie, ref_plaats1, functie, email, isnull(telefoon, mobiel) as 
telefoon,
personeelsnr,
CASE
    WHEN geslacht ='1' THEN 'Man'
    ELSE
    CASE WHEN geslacht ='2' THEN 'Vrouw'
    END
END as Geslacht
FROM VW_telefoonboek where achternaam = 'hovens'
```

These fields:

```
ref_aanhefinformeel, voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, ref_afdeling,
ref_locatie, ref_plaats1, functie, email, isnull(telefoon, mobiel) as 
telefoon,
personeelsnr,
```

don't exist in your view!

Comment: Koloms are the column names in my case. (This is a specific webview)

Comment: It can find them all, except for:
Invalid column name 'ref_plaats1'. Invalid column name 'ref_locatie'. Invalid column name 'ref_afdeling'. Invalid column name 'naam'.

Comment: I'm not able to =(.

Comment: They do exist btw, I get some results back if I remove the 4 with ref_ in the name.